# Animate transition of items when switching content view between ListView and GridView

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-animation

I am working on a feature to switch between list layout and grid layout of displayed data. Something similar that Google Drive application has both on Android and on iOS platform. I especially like animation that comes with the transition on iOS version of app, where items are moved to their new positions and resized instead of just appearing there.

One solution I thought of would be to have one custom ViewGroup that would have both ListView and GridView functionality and would use one or another based on a flag that would be set from client code. That way I would know positions of items in one layout when I am about to draw new items after switching to new layout.

One thing I was wondering is if there isn't more straightforward solution by using features from new transition framework from KitKat, because basically I can reuse loaded data in fragment and just switch between ListView and GridView. But nothing I know would import transition animations right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `GridLayout` and `GridView` are two different things. The latter is what you're interested in. Second, I think that the Drive app is only using a GridView and not a combination of List+Grid.

In a GridView, you can set the number of columns to 1 and it'll then behave like a ListView.

For animating the re-arrangement:

1. You need to store the co-ordinates of the visible children of
   GridView before the update happens.
2. Post update, move them to their old co-ordinates.
3. And then translate their position to (0, 0). Here, 0,0 is their
   relative to self positions, which would mean their actual positions.

Comment: I meant grid layout literally, not as a Java class. 

But it is true that I didn't realize that GridView can behave as ListView if number of columns is set to 1. 

Thus I have all the positions I need. I made similar animations with list addition and deletion, so it should be quite straightforward. 

I am going to test it, and if it is enough, I will accept the answer.

Comment: Great! If you've got your ListView update animation ready, implementing the same for a GridView would only require the addition of x-coordinates while animating their position changes. Good luck.